# Videojs get video dimensions in fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video.js

I am able to get the width & size of the actual video (not the player) when not in fullscreen mode using the videoWidth() and videoHeight(), like this:

```
var SVideo = videojs('SingularVideo').ready(function(){

    resizeFunc(this.videoWidth(), this.videoHeight())

  });
```

The problem is that I need to check the video size when the user enters fullscreen mode, so I listen on the "fullscreenchange" event and check again:

```
SVideo.on("fullscreenchange",
      function () {
          resizeFunc(SVideo.videoWidth(), SVideo.videoHeight());
  });
```

But in the fullscreenchange callback, the width and height don't change, the values are the same as if the video is not in fullscreen mode.
I would very much appreciate any suggestions as how to get the actual video width and height when in fullscreen mode. TIA!

Comment: videoWidth and videoHeight properties return the width and height of the media, not of the element. These do not change magically when you go to fullscreen.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Since it is on full screen, you can get the width and height of the screen using the code below:

```
var width = screen.width;
var height = screen.height;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, will this always be the actual video size? does the video get stretched if it is not the same aspect ratio? I need the size of the video, without the black borders. TIA!

Comment: hmm, I don't know. If you could provide a JSFiddle with your code, perhaps I could help more.

Comment: This is a missleading answer. The question is how to get video (not container) dimentions.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the video-dimensions, but not in fullscreen mode. I can see this is an old question, - so you probably don't have the issue still. But hopefully, it can help someone else.

---

I did find this in the documentation: [currentDimensions](https://docs.videojs.com/player#currentDimension) ... However... I was hoping to get the aspect ratio of the video, - and not the size of the video-element (including the black edges/borders/fillers). I did figure out, that if I set `fluid` to `true` ( [the fluid option](https://docs.videojs.com/player#fluid) ), then the video would take up the entire video-HTML-element.

Please note, that the fluid-option is implemented slightly after the video is rendered, - so I had to use setTimeout (uuuuuugly!), to get the correct aspectRatio.

Here is my (VueJS)-code:

```
mounted() {
  this.player = videojs(this.$refs.videoPlayer, this.videoOptions, () => {
    this.calcAspectRatio();
    this.setMaxWidth();

    setTimeout( () => {
      this.calcAspectRatio();
      this.setMaxWidth();
    });

    setTimeout( () => {
      this.calcAspectRatio();
      this.setMaxWidth();
    }, 1000 );

    setTimeout( () => {
      this.calcAspectRatio();
      this.setMaxWidth();
    }, 2000 );
  });
}

methods: {
  calcAspectRatio(){
    if( this.player && this.player.currentDimensions( 'width' ).width ){
      this.aspectRatio = this.player.currentDimensions( 'width' ).height / this.player.currentDimensions( 'width' ).width;
    }
  },
  setMaxWidth(){
    let maxWidth = 1 / this.aspectRatio * ( ( this.VIEWPORTHEIGHTWHICHISCALCULATEDELSEWHERE - 100 ) * 0.90 );
    document.querySelector( '#' + this.id ).style.maxWidth = maxWidth + 'px';
  },

}
```